# Emacs & LaTeX: amount of columns for tables/matrices/arrays

Tags: arrays, emacs, matrix, latex

Would anyone have a suggestion how to go about having for:

```latex
\begin{array}{cc}
Lorem & Ipsum \\
More & Stuff \\
\end{array}
```

Where adding or removing a `c`, `l` or `r` in the part after array would add or remove the `&` from all lines in the array environment.

Basically the same trick could then be applied to matrices or table environments.

At the least I'd be interested in how others go about this "easy-to-go-wrong", "hard-to-efficiently-alter" task.

Comment: There is an [Excel2LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex) add-in that you can use to manage your tables *outside* of LaTeX (in Excel) and then insert the generated code in your `.tex` file.

Comment: @Werner I really have a preference for an emacs related solution, in case I'd migrate to another OS. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Is there a way to count the amount of "&" (or probably more specific, "&" but not "\&" on each newline? Then that way it would be somehow possible to search for \begin and \end and use searches for \\ or something

Comment: @Dualinity: There's always LibreOffice.

Comment: @Dualinity See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52798/5701 for an example of counting symbols by searching and ignoring comments. In your case though, as you say, you would limit the searching and counting to a line. To find "&" but not "\&" you can write a regexp.

Comment: @N.N. Thank you, however I am not able to do that editing myself.

Comment: @Dualinity It is just a vague idea for a solution to a part of your problem. What might be harder is to come up with is how to reasonably construct the functionality you are after. If you write an elaborate specification of the functionality it might be easier to think of possible implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497189/emacs-latex-amount-of-columns-for-tables-matrices-arrays#comment16835580_12498189) you can make a [YASnippet](http://capitaomorte.github.com/yasnippet/) that according to the amount of letters in the second argument `array` automatically adds the appropriate amount of `&`s to the first row of the array:

```lisp
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: array
# key: arr
# expand-env: ((yas/indent-line 'fixed))
# --
\begin{array}{${1:cc}}$0
${1:$
(let ((row ""))
  (dotimes (i (- (string-width yas/text) 1) row)
    (setq row (concat row "& "))))
}\\\\
\end{array}
```

The manual [exemplifies this technique](http://capitaomorte.github.com/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#mirrors-with-transformations). The line with `(yas/indent-line 'fixed)` is to avoid AUCTeX indenting the row. The reason for placing the exit point of the snippet (`$0`) at the end of the declaration of the array rather than at the beginning of the first row is that when placed at the beginning of the first row the exit point does not behave as expected.

The following snippet will also add as many rows as there are columns:

```lisp
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: array
# key: arr
# expand-env: ((yas/indent-line 'fixed))
# --
\begin{array}{${1:cc}}$0
${1:$
(let ((row "") (allrows ""))
  (dotimes (i (- (string-width yas/text) 1))
    (setq row (concat row "& ")))
  (dotimes (i (string-width yas/text) allrows)
    (setq allrows (concat allrows row "\\\\\\\\\n"))))
}\end{array}
```

A problem with this snippet is that it adds `\\` even if there only one column but such arrays may be rare.

There seems to be problems with adding lisp comments to embedded lisp code in snippets so I simply add a commented version of only the lisp code to explain it:

```lisp
;; Make an empty row with as many columns as symbols in $1 (the $1 in
;; the snippet which is what yas/text refer to)
(let ((row "") (allrows ""))
  ;; Make an empty row with as many columns as symbols in $1
  (dotimes (i (- (string-width yas/text) 1))
    (setq row (concat row "& ")))
  ;; Make as many rows as symbols in $1
  (dotimes (i (string-width yas/text) allrows)
    (setq allrows (concat allrows row "\\\\\\\\\n"))))
```

Comment: Very good. I feel sad that I do not understand the code, but either way, thank you. If you would have a way to also influence the amount of rows so that the amount of rows is equal to the amount of columns (I suppose this would be the best estimate of the amount of rows needed), I would suppose it is a sufficient answer to the question (Though we still have the issue that @wvxvw was answering, where, once made, such a table is still difficult to edit).

Comment: @Dualinity I have added such a snippet. The code is very simple lisp so if you learn the basics of lisp you should understand it (I barely know the basics to this code may be all ugly!). I have indented the code to make it easier to read. I could add comments to if that would help you. Indeed, the difficulty of editing tables remains. I believe that [using Org-mode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12498189/789593) is the best solution to make and edit tables. Maybe you should ask for elaboration and examples to that answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

I usually generate the tables from a different format (tab separated values or org-mode tables) in which such operations are simpler.

Comment: I think my "not-so-pretty-solution" would be to create yasnippets for all the matrices and tables, for instance "tabu2" would create a tabular environment with 2 c's (so 1 "&"), "tabu3" with 3 c's.

Comment: @Dualinity You could also have the same [key](http://capitaomorte.github.com/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#key-snippet-abbrev) for all the snippets so that you may choose which matrix or table type you want on expansion. That way you do not have to memorize lots of new keys.

Comment: @N.N. I'm not a fan of prompts. Apart from creating all the snippets (which is the real trouble), it would have an obvious structure to remember (i.e. bmat3<TAB> = bmatrix with 3 ccc's while tabu3<TAB> would be the tabular environment with 3 ccc's). Another issue then is still if you want to remove a column afterwards.

Comment: @Dualinity Would a snippet that lets you enter whatever into the second braces of `array`, e.g. `cc`, and then adds as many `&` to the first line of the array be helpful? The last example of http://capitaomorte.github.com/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#mirrors-with-transformations shows such a technique.

Comment: @N.N. +1. It sure would. I got it so far to add in as many &'s as signs in there, however, how to add some whitespace in between of them?

Comment: \begin{array}{${1:ccc}}
${1:$(make-string (string-width text) ?\&)} \\
\end{array}
$0

Comment: @Dualinity I tried the following `\begin{array}{${1:ccc}}
${1:$(dotimes (i (string-width yas/text))(insert "& "))}\\\\ `  but it does not work. I dunno why the loop is only executed as the snippet is inserted but not as you change the value of `$1`.

Comment: @Dualinity In trying to debug the snippet I found http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.yasnippet.devel/479 which might interest you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not *exactly* the answer, but this is how I was doing it:

1. Align on &, for example: <kbd>C-x . &</kbd>.
2. Select the entire column I need using regular selection commands.
3. Cut a rectangular area by using <kbd>C-x r k</kbd>.

This is not super automatic, but given some exercise isn't really a hurdle, except, perhaps, if you have to re-format some old document and make a lot of changes all at once.

**EDIT**

```lisp
(defun latex-merge-next-column (start end column)
  "Works on selected region, removes COLUMN'th ampersand
in every line in the selected region"
  (interactive "r\nnColumn to merge: ")
  (labels ((%nth-index-of 
            (line)
            (let ((i -1) (times 0))
              (while (and (< times column) i)
                (setq i (position ?\& line :start (1+ i))
                      times (1+ times))) i)))
    (let ((region (split-string (buffer-substring start end) "\n"))
          amp-pos
          replacement)
      (dolist (line region)
        (setq amp-pos (%nth-index-of line)
              replacement
              (cons (if amp-pos
                        (concat (subseq line 0 amp-pos)
                                (subseq line (1+ amp-pos)))
                      line) replacement)))
      (kill-region start end)
      (insert (mapconcat #'identity (reverse replacement) "\n")))))
```

This would work on the selected region and remove the n'th ampersand in every line. You could bind it to some key that is comfortable for you, say:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-n") 'latex-merge-next-column)
```

Then <kbd>C-c C-n 2</kbd> would remove every second ampersand in the selected lines.

Comment: I am sorry, could you explain more? I cannot get my head around what this should be doing/how it works.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for the effort. I will probably make a function/macro from this :). Since indeed this is not the entire answer, I am going to give others a chance to give a complete answer.

Comment: I will make a macro that will search backwards for a "\begin{", go down one line, start the mark with C-U space, search forward for  "\end{", then use your "C-c C-." for & and \\, then pop the mark, save as macro and bind to key.

Comment: EDIT: For some reason it does not do a perfect align, I tried all different parameters for that align regexp with C-u C-x C-., but it does not line them up (some parts have empties, some parts have short words) Ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16936/discussion-between-dualinity-and-wvxvw)

Answer (score 1):

Building on the solution by @wvxvw, how about just using `M-x align-current` in the tabular/matrix/array environment and then manipulating using the block selection/insertion commands? This seems to work intelligently with escaped ampersands. I find it useful to disable wrapping during this operation. I don't find this hard to edit at all, as relatively regular re-alignment makes everything quite readable.